# Is it possible to use Team Build 2008 to build a VS 2005 solution targeting .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, tfsbuild

What are the necessary steps I have to do to get Team Build 2008 to build a Visual Studio 2005 solution targeting .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently all you have to do is install VS2005 on the build server and then:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/9afc874b-48b7-4f9f-a009-b92fd9404b39

I've managed to get it working by just copying the C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v8.0 folder over.